# Google Maps scrollBy camera animation not smooth

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I'm trying to animate the google map based on an onTouch MotionEvent on one of my ImageViews. The scroll does not animate smoothly. I feel as though this has to do with starting a new animation before the previous has had time to complete. I would like it to animate as smoothly as if I was to click and drag the map with my finger.

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(10, 10));
}
```

Comment: to answer my own question, I used a MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN to set a flag to true and a MotionEvent.ACTION_UP to set the same flag to false. I then do my animation in a while loop inside a thread and use googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(10, 10)); I also used a Thread.sleep() inside the while loop of the thread.